# Add multiple new attributes by checking the existing ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a reporting application that pulls info from different servers and displays them in a specific format. I am also making this completely responsive so the tables that I get look something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">Date</td>
    <td width="40%">Description</td>
    <td width="17%">Result</td>
    <td width="15%">Range</td>
    <td width="8%">Comments</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to know how I could add data-label to each depending on what width they have.

like

```html
<td width="30%" data-label="Date">Date</td>
```

I don't actually need the date field so I have hidden that entire field with CSS its just the description, result, range and comments.

Comment: So will "Date" *always* have `30%` width, "Description" *always* `40%`, etc.? How do you decide which label to apply?

Comment: Yes,  for some reason every <td> element in a mile long table has the same repeating width's so I thought that should be the decisive factor. The data label is exactly the same as mentioned above:

30% - Date
40% - Description
17% - Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling a list of all `td` elements in the document, and applying the appropriate labels when the widths-in-question are seen:

```js
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for ( var i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i )
  {
    var td = tds[i];
    var label = null;
    
    switch (td.getAttribute('width'))
    {
      case '30%':
        label = 'Date';
        break;
      case '40%':
        label = 'Description';
        break;
      case '17%':
        label = 'Result';
        break;
      case '15%':
        label = 'Range';
        break;
      case '8%':
        label = 'Comments';
        break;
    }
    
    if (label)
      {
        td.setAttribute('data-label', label);
      }
  }
```

```css
td[data-label=Date] {
  color: red;
}

td[data-label=Description] {
  color: green;
}

td[data-label=Result] {
  color: purple;
}

td[data-label=Range] {
  color: blue;
}

td[data-label=Comments] {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">Date</td>
    <td width="40%">Description</td>
    <td width="17%">Result</td>
    <td width="15%">Range</td>
    <td width="8%">Comments</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">Blah</td>
    <td width="40%">Blah</td>
    <td width="17%">Blah</td>
    <td width="15%">Blah</td>
    <td width="8%">Blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I also forgot. on the same code there are also side headers that  need to be identified. So in case the date, result, range and comments have just &nbsp; then I want to remove all data labels for that row and remove all <td> except description and add in rowspan="5"

Comment: That would make a perfectly good new question :-)  The additional logic is different, looking at things on a row level, which is completely ignored here.

Comment: cool no problem I have the question ready but I cannot post for another 33 mins. will paste the link here once I post it. :)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674559/remove-td-that-has-nbsp-and-make-sub-header) for the follow up question

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

One thing I'd suggest, though, is to use

```
<td style="width:30%;">Date</td>
```

instead of the width attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp

The width attribute is not HTML5 compliant.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var tds = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable td'); 
  
  for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
    tds[i].setAttribute('data-width', tds[i].getAttribute('width'));
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">Date</td>
    <td width="40%">Description</td>
    <td width="17%">Result</td>
    <td width="15%">Range</td>
    <td width="8%">Comments</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Rather than `querySelector('table')` and all the multi-level `children` access, why not just `document.getElementsByTagName('td')`, which will give you a list of *just* `td` elements to loop through. Also, OP likely needs a concrete suggestion on what `// Do something` should be replaced with.

Comment: @Paul Roub You're probably right with that. I wasn't sure what kind of selector to go for since I wasn't sure what else would be on the page, although I suppose getting all td's or getting the first tale is about the same in terms of what else you might accidentally hit. I've modified it for the best of both worlds

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily by creating an association on width:data-label

```
(function(){
    var assoc = {
                30: 'Date', 
                40: 'Description',
                17: 'Result',
                15: 'Range', 
                8: 'Comments'};

    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    for(x=0;x<tds.length;x++){
       tds[x].setAttribute('data-label', assoc[parseInt(tds[x].getAttribute('width'))]);
    }
();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
              $('#mytable tr td').each(function(){

                  console.log($(this).attr("data-width",$(this).text());
              })


          });
```

plz check it