# remove <td> that has &nbsp; and make sub header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am working on an application that reads data from servers that I do not have control over but I need to style the front end on this table to look like the others. the table looks something like this.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">Date</td>
    <td width="40%">Description</td>
    <td width="17%">Result</td>
    <td width="15%">Range</td>
    <td width="8%">Comments</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the `<tr>` blocks keep repeating for a mile. There are some rows that have the date, result, range and comments have just `&nbsp;` then I want to remove all data labels for that row and remove all `<td>` except description and add in `rowspan="5"`.

**FYI** this is a follow up question to my previous question. just to give a gist - I wanted to add in data-labels to every td element so that they show up using `:before` for a mobile device.

[here is the link to my previous Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673092/add-multiple-new-attributes-by-checking-the-existing-ones/30673969#30673969)

Thanks for the help

Comment: where are you stuck? There's no JS in your code snippet.

Comment: Btw your widths sum up to 110%. It might be on purpose, also might cause excess space on the columns..

Comment: The sum percent doesnt matter. the whole site is responsive so it fits in perfectly. Also I dont have control over the <td> widths they come from some sever which was coded by god knows who and we cannot touch that, also I am not using the first td thats 30% its hidden through css.

Comment: The width attribute on the td element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following function accomplishes what you want by doing:

1. Loop through all `<tr>`
2. Get all the `<td>` inside
3. Store the `<td>` at index 1 (Description)
4. Filter the remaining `<td>` collection and get the ones that just contain `&nbsp;`
5. If all are empty, remove them and adjust the properties of the remaining `<td>`

```js
$(function() {
  $("table tr").each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).find("td"); //find all td
    var descriptionTD = tds.eq(1); //get the td for the description
    
    //get the remaining tds that only contain "&nbsp;"
    var emptytds = tds.not(descriptionTD).filter(function() {
      return $(this).html() === "&nbsp;";
    });
    
    //if all the remaing tds are empty
    if (emptytds.length === tds.length - 1) {
      emptytds.remove();
      descriptionTD.prop("colspan", tds.length).prop("width", "100%");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">Date</td>
    <td width="40%">Description 1</td>
    <td width="17%">Result</td>
    <td width="15%">Range</td>
    <td width="8%">Comments</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40%">Description 2</td>
    <td width="17%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="15%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">Date</td>
    <td width="40%">Description 3</td>
    <td width="17%">Result</td>
    <td width="15%">Range</td>
    <td width="8%">Comments</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="40%">Description 4</td>
    <td width="17%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="15%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```